# Running NSTimer in Background

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nstimer

I've got NSTimer and I need it working when user turning off the app. I am new to Swift, so explain in detail please. I know that I need to use NSDate(), but I don't know how to do it.

I need a working timer when the user closes the application. And I need timer works until user will press on Stop.

Comment: You don't need a timer working when the app it is in the background, you only need the timer to update the UI, so you need to make the start date persist through launches using NSUserDefaults and restart your timer once the user opens the app again

Comment: Why would you need a timer when the user turn off the app? Is it a today widget ?

Comment: Leo, I need to count how much time app is turning on unless user will tap on stop. Just testing

Comment: just save the start date. The next time the user open the app just load the date from NSUSerdefaults to update the UI using that date.

Comment: Ok, thanks!
But, what will be if user will open the app and then turn it off again?

Comment: just set it to nil. And check it it is nil when you load your view if the start date it is not nil just load it and start the timer to update the UI

Comment: Thanks you, Leo! You just saved a lot of my time!